# Как обратиться к элементу массива

Tags: c#

Загнал текстовый файл в массив считав построчно и разделив запятой.Как обратиться к второму элементу строк, и загнать эти элементы в массив чтоб обработать LINQ запросом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
var list = File.ReadAllLines("data.txt");

var array = list.Select(x => x.Split(',')[1]).ToArray();
```

или с проверкой:

```
var array = list.Select(x => x.Split(',')).Where(x => x.Length > 1).Select(x => x[1]).ToArray();
```